# CSS height in % doesn't work only with React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, height

I have a wierd problem. I have exactly the same DOM and CSS rendered with React and rendered with pure HTML. However, in React children of the div.container doesn't get the proper height when it's set in %. It works well when it's set with vh or with px, but I can't use those. Any idea why? And how to fix this problem?

```css
div.form label:after, div.wrapper:after, div.container:after {
  display: block;
  content: '.';
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 319px;
  min-height: 479px;
  background-color:black;
}
div.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 1368px;
  max-width: 1368px;
  min-width: 319px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color:red;
}
nav {
  width: 82px;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 1368px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #55c7f9;
}
header {
  height: 15%;
  margin: 0 6%;
  float: initial;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  background-color:orange;
}
div.wrapper {
  min-height: calc(100% - 62px);
  height: auto;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  float: right;
  background-color:yellow;
}
div.main {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 158px);
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav></nav>
    <header></header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you check your browser console, you can definitely see a warning `Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?`

Comment: My problem is rendered DOM, not the react code. In react I use className, but setting height in % doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide proper details : wether code is rendered DOM or react code, which browser you are using, are you using webpack / browserify etc.

Comment: I use wbpack. This is rendered DOM by react and I also have the same DOm handwritten by me. While the handwritten code works well, the rendered code by react ignores height:%. However handwritten code doesn't need the webpack. May the webpack be the source of the problem? This issue is in every browser I've tested: Chrome, Firefox, IE, Vivaldi, Opera.

Comment: then add your React code also. Please read the guidelines for asking questions properly. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

class is className inside react.

```
<body>
  <div className="container">
    <nav></nav>
    <header></header>
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="main"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, but nope. I typed here rendered DOM, not the react code.

Answer (score 1):

Some advice that *might* help you..

Add html, along with body.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Make sure the div your bundle is being loaded to has height: 100%;. In the case below "root" would need it.

```
<body>
  <div class="root"></div>
  <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Last case, if you do something like this:

```
<div>{this.props.children}</div>
```

Make sure you give this div a className and add it to the list of things that need to be 100%

Comment: This worked for me. Just had to set my react root element with 100% height.